# Is there a way to word wrap the text in a button?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an ActiveX button that has a long line of text to it.  It's long enough that it cuts off the text.

Is there a way to wordwrap the button?

Comment: increasing button's height should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable word wrap under the properties:

1. `Right click` the button
2. Click `Properties`
3. At the bottom should be `WordWrap`
4. Set this to `True`

[image]

Comment: thanks jonno, cant believe that i didn't see that in the properties. one gold star for you